# Opacity onscroll, Script won't work

Tags: jquery, onload, onscroll

Hey guys im trying to achieve the onscroll functionality but it won't work on my site.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

/* Check the location of each desired element */
$('.hideme').each( function(i){

var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

 /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
 if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

 $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

 }

 }); 

 });

});</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
<div class="hideme">Fade In</div>

</div>
</body>
```

And link to the Site for full code:
http://eren-web-design-development.tk/C-Html/landingpage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the error

```
TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
```

in my console. I think $ is conflicting with some other library in your code. Anyway, try this and check if it is working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
..

}
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome, thanks a lot. It is proper now, but is there a possibility to view just one of the hideme containers after it was scrolled on and the second if it was scrolled further? And so on?

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Cool. Glad to help. You can accept my answer btw :)

Comment: This is not perfect, but try something like this:

if( $(this).position().top < $(window).scrollTop() + 400 ){
   $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
}

Comment: Youre genious thats really awesome, need to dive in further with jquery to fully understand that, but it works fine, very similar to php

Comment: Haha.. happy to know it worked. jQuery is simple.. just keep doing stuff you'll get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

I looked on your site and think the problem is you jQuery.
It's propably not loading correctly.

$ is defined. But when I do $("html") it returns null.
When I use jQuery("html") it does return correctly.

Something else is taking up the $ variable.

Comment: Thank you also, thats right. In order to use the script on my page i need to give it a unique function id. Im using Joomla so there are much possibilites that it is used in another function.

Comment: Ah, okay. Good luck with the rest of your site.^^